# Reduction from NP-complete problem to unknown complexity problem and vice-versa

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np

Suppose I have two problems: $B$, which is NP-complete, and $A$, of unknown complexity.

Question:

- If I show that $B \le A$ I can state that $A$ is also NP-complete because the two required conditions are satisfied: (i) $A$ is in NP; (ii) I reduced a NP-complete problem to $A$.
- If I show that $A \le B$ I can say that $B$ is at least hard as $A$, so $A$ is at least NP-complete, but can be harder.

Are these statements correct?

Comment: In your second statement, how can you say A is "at least" when $A \le B$ ?

Comment: The second statement is false: reducing A to B does not imply A’s NP-completeness. A could be in P, for example. In the first: how do you conclude that A is NP? If A is of unknown complexity it could be EXP-complete, for example.

Comment: Also the first statement is incorret: if $B \leq A$ then $A$ (of "unknown complexity") is **NP-hard**; in order to prove that it is NP-complete you must also prove that it is contained in $NP$.

Answer (score 2):

I shall assume "$\le$" indicates a poly-time, many-one (i.e., Karp) reduction. This seems to be the case since you are referring to NP-completeness.

> If I show that $B \le A$ I can state that A is also NP-complete because the two required conditions are satisfied: (i) A is in NP (ii) i reduced a NP -complete problem to A.

If $B \le A$, that is, $B$ is reducible to $A$, then $A$ is necessarily $\mathbf{NP}$-hard, that is, any problem in $C \in \mathbf{NP}$ is reducible to $A$ (i.e., $C \le A$). This is because any problem $C \in \mathbf{NP}$ is reducible to $B$ (due to the $\mathbf{NP}$-completeness of $B$) and we have $C \le B \le A$; using the transitivity of (this form of) reduction we obtain $C \le A$. However, *this does not at all imply* that $A \in \mathbf{NP}$—otherwise, any $\mathbf{NP}$-hard problem would be $\mathbf{NP}$-complete! To prove $A$ is $\mathbf{NP}$-complete, thus, you would also have to prove $A \in \mathbf{NP}$ separately.

> If I show that $A \le B$ I can say that $B$ is at least hard as $A$, so $A$ is at least NP-complete, but can be harder.

$A \le B$ means $A$ is reducible to $B$, which can be reformulated as $B$ being at least as hard as $A$, as you have stated. In no way does this imply that $A$ is $\mathbf{NP}$-complete. Granted, it could be the case, but, for all we know, $A$ could be in $\mathbf{P}$, a regular language, or even trivial (i.e., $\Sigma^\ast$ or $\varnothing$).